# Create a symbolic link do navigate with cd

Tags: symlink

Is it possible to create a symbolic link to easier change directories? like

`ln -s /Users/mles/Documents /usr/local/bin/d`

so I can `cd d` instead of `cd ~/Documents`?

Comment: Here is a generic answer to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/97312/22003 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with creating a symbolic link in that manner is that you are limited to where the symbolic link is created.  It also adds to the problem if you have a directory `../d/..` somewhere on your system.

There are a couple of ways to solve this....

#### Create an Alias

In terminal, you can create an alias by issuing the command

`alias cdd='cd ~/Documents'`

The benefit here is that it will work anywhere without having to add it to your PATH.

To make it permanent, add the command to your `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

#### Make a variable cd-able

Also, in your `.bash_profile` add the following

```
shopt -s cdable_vars 
export Docs=$HOME/Documents
```

Now, when you type `cd Docs` it will expand out `HOME` to whatever your user directory is plus the directory you specified. (`/Users/yourusername/Documents`)

Personally, I did this with a variable called icloud as follows:

```
export  icloud=$HOME/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
```

Now, I can reference my iCloud documents location without having to remember that lengthy path.

Answer (score 1):

You can define variables pointing to your directories. For example:

```
[~]$ export d=~/Documents

[~]$ ls -l $d
[~]$ cd $d
[~/Documents]$
```

In bash you can use `cdable_vars` option to be able to `cd` without preceding `$`:

```
[~]$ shopt -s cdable_vars
[~]$ export d=~/Documents

[~]$ cd d
[~/Documents]$
```

But it does not allow dropping `$` for other commands, so `ls -l d` won't work.